# error code 1064: syntax error in SQL query

Tags: mysql

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with below python query?SU_version is of datatype varchar(45) ,let me know if any details are required.

```
SELECT gerrit_id
FROM gerrit_table
where (SU_version>=00.00.0086
       and SUversion<=00.00.0085
       and PL=LA.BF64.1.1 
       and component=SU_CNSS_BT_FM_Redfox64);
```

Answer (score 1):

Presumably the problem are the constants.  These look like strings, so they should be surrounded by single quotes:

```
SELECT gerrit_id
FROM gerrit_table
WHERE SU_version >= '00.00.0086' and SUversion <= '00.00.0085' and
      PL = 'LA.BF64.1.1' and component = 'SU_CNSS_BT_FM_Redfox64';
```

Comment: for sample data as below,it doesnt show any output when infact there is data....gerrit_id SU_version PL component
960840 00.00.0086 LA.BF64.1.1 SU_CNSS_BT_FM_Redfox64
984920 00.00.0086 LA.BF64.1.1 SU_CNSS_BT_FM_Redfox64
984973 00.00.0084 LA.BF64.1.1 SU_CNSS_BT_FM_Redfox64
985164 00.00.0086 LA.BF64.1.1 SU_CNSS_BT_FM_Redfox64
986446 00.00.0084 LA.BF64.1.1 SU_CNSS_BT_FM_Redfox64
986667 00.00.0086 LA.BF64.1.1 SU_CNSS_BT_FM_Redfox64
987585 00.00.0085 LA.BF64.1.1 SU_CNSS_BT_FM_Redfox64
987785 00.00.0086 LA.BF64.1.1 SU_CNSS_BT_FM_Redfox64

Comment: is there a way to attach or share sample data on stackoverflow?

Comment: The best approach is to set up a SQL Fiddle example (www.sqlfiddle.com).

Answer (score 0):

You said that SU_version is varchar, so why are you using >= in where clause, maybe try to cast it before using >= and also in your pl, you should enclose it in quotes try this code

```
SELECT gerrit_id
FROM gerrit_table
where (cast(SU_version as double)>=00.0086
   and SUversion<=00.00.0085
   and PL='LA.BF64.1.1' 
   and component='SU_CNSS_BT_FM_Redfox64');
```

I don't know what is `LA.BF64.1.1` and `SU_CNSS_BT_FM_Redfox64`, so i assume they're just user input, hope this will help